# Im trying to make an unban command for my discord server, but its not splitting the name and discriminator. Can anybody give any tips?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Python is saying "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)" referring to the 4th line of code. I have searched up tutorials because I am new to discord.py and none of them seem to help.

I've tried unbanning a user without splitting the name and discriminator and I couldn't get that to work either.

```
@client.command()
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')    
    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user
        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
            return
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to split them? It would make much more sense to convert `user` to a [`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#user) object and then unban this user (this cannot be a [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) object since the user is not a guild member anymore).

```py
@client.command()
async def unban(ctx, *, user=None):

    try:
        user = await commands.converter.UserConverter().convert(ctx, user)
    except:
        await ctx.send("Error: user could not be found!")
        return

    try:
        bans = tuple(ban_entry.user for ban_entry in await ctx.guild.bans())
        if user in bans:
            await ctx.guild.unban(user, reason="Responsible moderator: "+ str(ctx.author))
        else:
            await ctx.send("User not banned!")
            return

    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send("I do not have permission to unban!")
        return

    except:
        await ctx.send("Unbanning failed!")
        return

    await ctx.send(f"Successfully unbanned {user.mention}!")
```

The advantage of this is the fact that you can specify an ID, mention, name or name+discrim.

Comment: Why use the converter manually instead of as a type hint in the arguments?

Comment: Not to be rude but with your code it keeps returning "Error: user could not be found!" even though the mentioned user is in the bans list. I tried mentions, user ID and just the name and discrimination and it still seems to not find them.

Comment: "from discord.ext import commands" is exactly what I have written

Comment: The bot doesn't reply at all but in shell its saying  " raise BadArgument('User "{}" not found'.format(argument))
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: User "Test Account#4827" not found"

Comment: I'm using version 1.2.2

Comment: The bot has all permissions. It can ban the account but not unban it.

Comment: It looks like the [`UserConverter`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/converter.py#L148) uses `get_user` instead of `fetch_user`, so if the user isn't in the cache it wont be able to find them. You should be able to write your own converter with similar logic that uses `fetch_user` to actually go get the user information.